# A <form:errors> block that only shows non-field errors?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible to configure a [`<form:errors/>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.errors) element that only shows non field errors?

I've tried the following, but of course it lists *all* errors both field and non-field.

```
<resource:hasBindErrors name="dualEntryForm">
    <div class="errorText">Please correct the following errors:</div>
    <div class="errorText"><form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorBox" /></div>
</resource:hasBindErrors>
```

Is there a path expression that doesn't show the field errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried omitting form:errors path attribute at all?

```
<resource:hasBindErrors name="dualEntryForm">
    <div class="errorText">Please correct the following errors:</div>
    <div class="errorText"><form:errors cssClass="errorBox" /></div>
</resource:hasBindErrors>
```